# bash catenate strings right to left

Tags: bash, tomcat, catalina, fiware-knowage

I'm debugging this catalina.sh script, at this point:

```
echo "$CATALINA_HOME"
  echo "dot " .
  echo "179"
  if [ -r "$CATALINA_HOME"/bin/setclasspath.sh ]; then
    echo "qui 81"

    . "$CATALINA_HOME"/bin/setclasspath.sh
  else
    echo "185"
    echo "Cannot find $CATALINA_HOME/bin/setclasspath.sh"
    echo "This file is needed to run this program"
    exit 1
  fi
```

output is:

```
 /home/sysadm/2_KNOWAGE/Knowage_6-2_ARES/Knowage-Server-CE 
 dot  . 
 179
 185
 /bin/setclasspath.shsadm/2_KNOWAGE/Knowage_6-2_ARES/Knowage-Server-CE
 This file is needed to run this program
```

when actually setclasspath.sh exixts, has write permissions and is where it's supposed to be. So I expect it to be found and run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly to do with line endings. I strongly suspect that CATALINA_HOME is picking up a carriage return character because it has been saved with Windows line endings.

Try running the script through `dos2unix` to strip the carriage returns.

You might also want to check that your editor is set to use Unix line ends rather than Windows ones.